# :hover doesn't work if hovered on :before pseudo generated content

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element, css-content

I am using a combination of css `:before` and `:hover` to add an image in a button.

The problem that I have encountered is that when I hover over the `:before` element, it triggers the image position change correctly but not the `li:hover` which created the `:before` element. 
I am guessing this is caused because of the way in which the `:before` element is sitting on top of the `li` which then prevents the `:hover` from being triggered.

Here is an image to better explain what is happening:

[image]

here is my css:

```
.columnStat ol li {
    list-style: none;
    margin-right: 3px;
    display: inline-block;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}

#page .columnStat ol {
    margin: 0px 8px;
    padding-top: 8px;
}

body {
    line-height: 1;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 10px 10px;
    color: rgb(35, 35, 35);
    font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    font-size: 0.75em;
}
a {
}
a:link {
    color: rgb(0, 102, 204);
    text-decoration: underline;
}
a:visited {
    color: rgb(0, 102, 204);
    text-decoration: none;
}
.columnStat ol > li > a, .columnStat ol > li > span {
    padding: 6px 7px 6px 20px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(190, 190, 190);
    border-image: none;
    color: rgb(89, 89, 89);
    text-decoration: none;
}
.columnStat ol li a:hover{
    background-color:#7c7c7c !important;
    border:1px solid #717171;
    color:#fff;
    cursor:pointer;
    background-image:none;
}
.vbt_true:before, .vbt_false:before {
    display: inline-block;
    content: "";
    width: 15px;
    height: 28px;
    background: transparent url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Chc7.png) no-repeat;
    float:left;
    margin-right:-15px;
    margin-top:-4px;
    position:relative;
}
.vbt_false:before {
    background-position: 3px -1px;
}
.vbt_true:before {
    background-position: -14px -1px;
}
.vbt_false:hover:before, .vbt_false.act:before {
    background-position: 3px -31px;
}
.vbt_true:hover:before, .vbt_true.act:before {
    background-position: -14px -31px;
}
```

and the HTML:

```
<div id="containerAdmin">
    <div id="page">
        <div class="columnStat">
            <ol>
                <li class="vbt_true"><a href="#">Button Text</a>
                </li>
                <li class="vbt_false"><a href="#">Button Text</a>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is a working **fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/wf_4/B42SH/

[image: SamleImage]

Comment: It works for me - the background color changes to gray. Are you seeing something different when you try your fiddle?

Comment: Really? I have tested this in IE 11, Chrome and FF and they all behave the same. When you hover on the left of the button, the rectangle disappears but the button does not go grey, that only happens when I hover on the right (over the text)

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I thought you were referring to the whole button. My mistake.

Comment: `li:hover:before` and `a:hover` are 2 different elements, behavior has nothing wrong, if you hover only `<li>`, why should `<a>` react if you do not set it in CSS as : `li:hover a` http://jsfiddle.net/B42SH/3/

Comment: Yes @GCyrillus well spotted. I have tweaked the selectors from `.columnStat ol li a:hover` to `.columnStat ol li:hover a` and this also solved the hover problem but without the `pointer-events: none;`, it creates a dead spot on the button where the pseudo content sits.

Comment: @GCyrillus Even I was going to answer the same on first place but as wf4 said, it is not clickable which makes the UX bad

Comment: @Mr.Alien I only reminds that `li:hover` doesnt trigger `a:hover` :) and so that `:before` should be use on `a` , not `li`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use [`pointer-events: none;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) so that even if you *hover* the `:before` generated pseudo content, it will simply behave as if you are hovering the normal button.

```
.vbt_true:hover:before, .vbt_true.act:before {
    background-position: -14px -31px;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/B42SH/2/)</kbd>

---

From [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events#Summary) :

> In addition to indicating that the element is not the target of mouse
>   events, the value `none` instructs the mouse event to go "through" the
>   element and target whatever is "underneath" that element instead.

---

You may find support not that impressive for IE *(As usual)*...

[image: pointer-events property support table]

<sup>Credits: Mozilla Developer Network</sup>

---

But we always have [polyfills](https://github.com/kmewhort/pointer_events_polyfill) available

Comment: That is perfect, I was worried that this would not be possible but its the type of thing that unless you know what you are looking for, you will never find it. Thank you, great answer.